# Python dictionary decreasing sorting

Tags: python-3.x

I want to sort my dictionary decreasing.

```
dic = { "one" = 5, "two" = 8, "three" = 1, "four" = 3}
```

output should be:

```
("two", 8)
("one", 5)
("four", 3)
("three", 1)
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I would like to do it with this code: for item in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]): but I can't chage it, so that I get my dictionary sorted DECREASING

Comment: dictionary building is not right. it should be: `dic = { "one": 5, "two":8, "three": 1, "four": 3}`

Comment: btw this question seems like a class homework. no research effort is shown.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` supports the keyword `reverse`. Set it to `True` for a reversed sorting order.

```
>>> dic = {"one": 5, "two": 8, "three": 1, "four": 3}
```

One way:

```
>>> [(k, dic[k]) for k in sorted(dic, key=dic.get, reverse=True)]
[('two', 8), ('one', 5), ('four', 3), ('three', 1)]
```

or:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(dic.items(), key=itemgetter(1),  reverse=True)
[('two', 8), ('one', 5), ('four', 3), ('three', 1)]
```

Here `itemgetter(1)` does the same as `lambda x: x[1]`, which in turn is equivalent to:

```
def get_index_one(x):
    return x[1]
```

i.e.

```
>>> sorted(dic.items(), key=get_index_one,  reverse=True)
[('two', 8), ('one', 5), ('four', 3), ('three', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way:

```
>>> dic = { "one" : 5, "two" : 8, "three" : 1, "four" : 3}
>>> sorted(dic.items(), key = lambda x:x[1],reverse = True)
[('two', 8), ('one', 5), ('four', 3), ('three', 1)]
```